# Derivative of Green function of Fractional Laplacian

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, reference-request, elliptic-equations

Let $G$ be the Green function of the Fractional Laplacian $(-\Delta)^s$ in a domain $\Omega$ (which is known explicitly for the special case of the ball: [link](https://web.ma.utexas.edu/mediawiki/index.php/Fractional_Laplacian#Green.27s_function_for_the_ball)). Does  $\nabla_x G(0,z)$ satisfy
$$(-\Delta)^s\nabla_x G(0,z) = 0 \text{ in } \Omega \ ?$$
In other words I'm asking if $\nabla_x$ and $(-\Delta)^s$ commute *on a bounded domain $\Omega$*

Comment: I suppose it depends on your definition of the fractional Laplacian on bounded domains. If it is the spectral theory definition, then the Laplacian commutes with the gradient, hence so does its fractional powers (and any function of it).